# UI says nothing while retrieving blog post information (seems nothing's going on)

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

While I was adding my blog post in my Stack Overflow developer story, I noticed this problem. When I paste the link in the box and press <kbd>Continue</kbd>, it takes some time to retrieve information, which is okay. But while the information is being retrieved, no indication is shown. It would better to tell the user something like, "please wait..", anything that indicates the work is going in behind the scene.

I understand that most of us may get it easily that there's been a process going on, but still, it's better to notify the user anyway.